# PHP Unable to load dynamic library with api.dll from external softaware

Tags: api, dll, wampserver, php

Hi everyone I need your help 
I tried to install an api from a external software and the api is on a dll file call `TheAPI.dll`. I use Wampserver all services works goods (apache, php and sql) my icon is green but in my php log file I've got this line :

```
  Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_theapi.dll' - could not load the module.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

I have already set up a dll file before and it work well it's appear on my `phpinfo()`.
But this time with this api it doesn't work I have got nothing on `phpinfo()`. I follow the same process for install a dll :

> 1)past the dll file on this path : `c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/`
>
> 2)i renamed the dll file with the prefix php_*my_dll_name*.dll
>
> 3) I added the extension into my php.ini  `extension=php_theapi.dll`  [my
>   php extension is load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkczo.png)

Wampserver load perfectly my extension you can see it on the picture below: But in phpinfo() my `php_theapi.dll` doesn't appear why ??

I really need help I follow many forum but anyone find the solution.
Thank you

Comment: What do you refer to with "my php log file"? If you are using php as a module within an http server (as opposed to using it as a CGI or fastCGI or as CLI application), then the http servers error log file would be the place to look.

Comment: Most likely that library is not compatible with the given php or http server executable. That may be if the library has been compiled against another version for example. But indeed I would expect some sort of error message indicating that.